# How can I prove that a flight was delayed by more than 4 hours?

Tags: compensation

My grandma is trying to request compensation under [Regulation (EC) No 261/2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004#Delays) from Air Transat, as her flight from England landed 4 hours past the scheduled arrival time in Canada. She recorded the time, but her telephone obviously isn't probative evidence.

But Air Transat refused, and countered:

> The delay of your flight was under the 4-hour mark. Regulation EC261/2004 does not apply.

So how can she prove the delay of more than 4 hours, free of charge?

Answer (score 3):

Flight delay is based on the scheduled arrival time, not the departure time. Was the arrival (when the plane doors opened) within 4 hours of scheduled arrival? If the answer is yes, Air Transat probably got away with it this time.

Comment: Yes. I updated this on my post.

Comment: Personally I've never seen airlines denying the duration of delay, as also mentioned in the other post you've linked, the downside of doing so is just too great. Perhaps your grandma can clearly state to them what is the scheduled arrival and what is the actual arrival time? Threatening to take this to regulators usually help too.